# Alpha tester could not test the assistant agent on tablet

Tags: actions-on-google

My alpha tester could not test the Actions I have published as Alpha version.

Instead of talking to my Actions, Google Assistant returns the search result even if I used the simple invocation phrase provided. However, this issue does not happened if I uses the developer account in Assistant.

Comment: Did this tester accept that they could test the Action in the Assistant directory?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, they have accepted.

Comment: Are they in a language/locale that matches your Action configuration? Did they wait a few hours for the configuration to be updated?

Comment: @NickFelker They have been waited for at least 2 days and the locale settings matches the required

Comment: Do you still experience this issue?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov Seems resolved for one of my Project. But still another one has it.